# Can't see Cloudformation change set added resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My cloudformation change set shows my change set completed and that my subnet has been added, but it does not show up under the subnets for my VPC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the changes? The screenshot only shows planned actions, not executed actions.

Comment: yeah, that was it. I forgot to actually execute it.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Comment: I will accept your answer. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The cause of the issue was not executing the changset. The solution was to [actually execute it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets-execute.html) for changes to happen.